How to Pass Tenant ID to FastAPI Microservices for Database Operations in a Django-Tenants Setup?
I'm relatively new to Django-tenants. My goal is to develop a SaaS application that runs on Kubernetes, where each tenant has its own database. For scalability and fault tolerance, I'm considering using FastAPI as microservices to manage individual modules separately.
Architecture example
Would it be advisable to structure the application this way, or would it be better to stick with a monolithic Django architecture and compromise on individual scalability?
If it is recommended, how should I structure FastAPI to handle tenant-specific operations, such as using an X-Tenant-ID header in AJAX requests to determine the appropriate CRUD operations?
I tried to send the tenant ID via AJAX (Header: X-Teantn-ID: 1) to the FastAPI microservice, but FastAPI is unable to establish a connection to the database using the tenant ID.

Unless you have a specific reason, I'd recommend using schemas instead of separate DBs.  Schemas scale better, and are easier to implement.

What do you mean by "FastAPI is unable to establish a connection to the database using the tenant ID"? Of course you can make that work, you just have to code it.

But also: one of the main principles of (micro)service based architecture is that each service should own its own database. Especially with SQL databases, having two applications use the same database will quickly become a mess, especially once schema migrations come into play. You could use separate schemas, but separate databases are usually preferable. Depending on wether this is reasonable in your usecase, I would or would not keep everything in the Django application.
